# @OneToOne field value not loaded after save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data JPA Project, my entity is the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "delivery_offers")
public class DeliveryOffer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "DELIVERY_ID")
private Delivery delivery;

... other fields
```

The table also has a foreign key for DELIVERY_ID which references to DELIVERY.ID

My Dao is a JpaRepository object, I try to persist a DeliveryOffer with dao.saveAndFlush (deliveryOffer).
I also set delivery.id = xy
I would like to return the persisted DeliveryOffer object, so I make in my controller

```
return dao.saveAndFlush(deliveryOffer)
```

The problem is, that in the returned DeliveryOffer the referenced Delivery object fields are all null except of the id, which I set for deliveryOffer.delivery.id (the Delivery exists in the DB with the given id)

If I try to get an "older" deliveryOffer from a recent transaction with findOne, the referenced delivery is then filled correctly.

So I suppose, it has to do something with the transaction. I thought, saveAndFlush commits it immediately, so in the return object I would await the correct entity.

Do you have an idea, why the delivery is empty at this point?

Comment: how are you setting `delivery` on your `deliveryOffer` object prior to persisting it?

Comment: deliveryOffer comes in the @RequestBody of the controller, it's constructed from JSON on the GUI. In the request deliveryOffer the field delivery already has a Delivery instance, with only the id field filled.

Comment: You need to hydrate that with the persistent object, e.g. `do.setDelivery(deliveryDao.get(do.getDelivery().getId());` or something similar.

Comment: Yes, that would work for sure, but I wanted to avoid an additional call because of performance reasons.
However I did a bit research, and maybe what I want to achieve is not possible with JPA at all.

Comment: There's nothing in JpaRepository that indicates it would hydrate disconnected objects.  In my experience with Hibernate (granted not spring data) this was not feasible without flushing, clearing and getting the object from the session.